Sonarqube is showing wrong result for React, TypeScript and JSX
Sonarqube is unable to understand the code for React, TypeScript and JSX, it is showing false positive across the application. Below is some code:
<div className="title-wrapper">
  <div className="card-title h5">Some Heading</div>
  <p className="card-sub-title">
    Some Label:
    <b className="text-nc-3"> {somedata} </b>
  </p>
</div>


